# Glassfish LOG4J loggin diferent applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, glassfish, log4j

I have many applications (war, ejb) in same glassfish server, the applications have different log4j configuration

app1.war -> log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, infcore
log4j.appender.infcore=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.infcore.File=/var/log/app1info.log
log4j.appender.infcore.MaxFileSize=20000KB
log4j.appender.infcore.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.infcore.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.infcore.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%5p] [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

app2.jar -> log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, infoejb
log4j.appender.infoejb=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.infoejb.File=/var/log/ejbinfo.log
log4j.appender.infoejb.MaxFileSize=20000KB
log4j.appender.infoejb.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.infoejb.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.infoejb.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%5p] [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

app3.war -> log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, infoapp2
log4j.appender.infoapp2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.infoapp2.File=/var/log/infoapp2.log
log4j.appender.infoapp2.MaxFileSize=20000KB
log4j.appender.infoapp2.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.infoapp2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.infoapp2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%5p] [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

I call logger:

```
protected static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(JAXSecurutyValidation.class);
```

The problem is that the information is recorded in only one file the ejb, the others files are not created.

How can I fix it?

SOLVED
I find the solution, is very simple update to glasfish 5 and all works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
String log4jfile = "log4 file path";
PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jfile);
```

You can call each log4j file for each application.

Comment: This code says log4j to use this properties file. So i think you should put this code when your application is upping.

Comment: I have implement ServletContextListener, and I put the code on contextInitialized but now all applications take this configuration and log in this file

Comment: I find the solution, is very simple update to glasfish 5 and all works fine, thanks.